# Logic Puzzle from the International Space Station

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

Here is a logic puzzle I can't solve. Can someone please help me to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Short answer: turn to page 110

Comment: I don't have the book ~~ I don't know where it comes from

Comment: i cant read this - have you got a text version?

Comment: sorry man. I don't. I only have the PDF version. I use a paper to write

Comment: Sorry guys. I know it may be uneasy to work on, but I really don't have any other way.

Comment: Usually page 3 contains **pretty** interesting stuff, I guess !

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE @Patrick. Can you figure out some obvious stuff so that we could begin.

Comment: Maybe you should [try it yourself first](http://logic-puzzles.org/how-to-solve-a-logic-puzzle.php)

Comment: It looks pretty mechanical. For example: Rule 1: Ariel isn't Commander - so put an X in the box where Ariel and Command meet. Then do likewise for Malik and Sasha and the next two jobs. Then repeat for the next rule. By the time you get to the bottom, you either have your answer, or you have enough information that going through the rules again will allow you to put extra crosses, and ticks. Repeat until done.

Comment: yes. but the info is just not enough by the time we go through everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my solution.

> [image: logic solution]

Table:

> `Person    Role               Lead           Assist`
>  `Arielle   astronaut          space walk     maintenance`
>  `Malik     science officer    observation    space walk`
>  `Neil      first flight eng   safety supply  replen`
>  `Ron       commander          maintenance    safety`
>  `Sasha     second flight eng  supply replen  observation`

Really not sure how to post the process, since it there were many small steps.

Comment: is there any clues for sentence 9 and 10??

Comment: Those clues helped fill in the bottom of the segment that crosses Roles and Leads. I also made a few assertions, and traced them out. When I got as far as I could go, I tested those assertions against 10 mostly but other clues were involved.

Comment: I get the point. You are saying sometimes we just need to try a little bit. like we assume who is what and test whether it is right or not~

Comment: Right, but you want to do that at a place when there are only two options.

Answer (score 2):

There are two key pieces of info that need to be inferred from multiple clues at the same time.  Instead of solving the whole puzzle for you (which I did), I will instead give you what the clues were.

1. Clue 5 states that Neil is going to assist in supply replenishment
   or station maintenance.  Clue 4 states that the leader of the
   station maintenance is either Neil or Ron.  If Neil were leading
   that mission, then he could not assist in it as well (main problem),
   so he would therefore assist in supply replenishment.  However, #4
   also states that this cannot happen.  Therefore, Ron is leading
   station maintenance, and Neil assists in Supply Replenishing.
2. At some point you will come to clues 7 and 8 which indicate
   consecutive names issues.  One of the items will only have two names
   available to choose from, and the other will have three.  By looking
   closely at the names, you will see that there is only one possible
   solution for these two clues.  If you still run into problems with
   this one, let me know and I can expand (don't want to give too much
   away yet).
3. Clues 9 and 10.  If you have followed everythign lgocially so far,
   your grid should be filled out like this...

[image]

Note that Clue 10 states that the 2nd Flight Engineer isn't leading the mission assisted by the Commander.  Since the 2nd engineer is leading the Supply mission, you can mark off that assist value under Commander (Cell D12 in my screenshot.  Keep using that type of "subtractive logic" through the rest of Clue 10 and 9, and you will end up with the final solution.

Comment: Person Role                              Lead                       Assist
Arielle Astronaut                         Space walk      Station maintenance
Malik Science officer      Earth observation     Space walk
Neil          Commander                Safety briefing          Supply replenishing
Ron      First flight engineer      Station maintenance      Safety briefing
Sasha Second flight engineer Supply replenishing    Earth observation

Comment: I think something wrong happened i don't know where.

Comment: What were you trying to do Patrick?

Comment: I solved the question. but I was being told the answer is wrong

Comment: is there any clues for sentence 9 and 10?

Comment: See my update above.

Comment: Thanks, man. I have everything understood before sentence 9 and 10. For the blanks I cannot fill, I tried the method by assuming who is what and got the final answer, Thank you anyway~